# Facebook token - Data Access Expiry

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've managed to get a Access Token that doesn't expire, however I've noticed that Data Expiry does have about a 3-month expiry lifespan on it.

From reading Facebook's own [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/), it appears that the access is based on when the user is `last active`.

> Facebook Login also enables you to ask for permissions when people log in to your app. These permissions, if granted by the user, give your app access to items of user data. For example, your app can access a user's name and profile photo.
>
> If an app asks for permissions, it is often necessary to put the app through app review so that Facebook can make sure that data is not misused. Your app can ask for people's name and photo (the default profile fields) and for email without going through app review, but all other permissions require review. For lists of permissions and which ones require app review, see Permissions Reference.

Does this mean that as long as I log into my Facebook profile that's linked - my Data Access will be extended? `

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to logging in to your FB profile, but logging in to your app.

Comment: Does "logging in to your app" mean when it was last used? 

For example, if I keep on using my access_token every few hours - will that extend the expiry of my data access?

Comment: No, it refers to authenticating your app by going through it's Login flow

Comment: Is there any way to automate this? For example can I call an API to refresh the token? Or do I need to go through the FB login flow/interface.

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this? Do you have to FB login flow to update the Data Access exipre date?

Comment: @mikemike396: Answered below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the token gets extended if it's being consistently used.

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Are you using native sdk via iOS, Android, or JS? Or are you using the Graph Api? Also have you found out what causes it to extend? What calls specifically? /me /feed etc?

Comment: NodeJs Authentication, and using the Insights Scope.

Comment: Which calls trigger the renewal/extension though? :D

Comment: I am using JavaScript SDK but it is not getting extended for me. How did you do the extension?